# laravel one to many return null on one side

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship, one-to-many

i have a one to many relation that return value on one side and null in the other side !!

```
class Particular extends Eloquent 

public function calls()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Call');
}
```

this relation ships return values

```
[

    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": "2014-10-16",
        "time": "12:12:12",
        "quote_id": 1,
        "repairman_id": 17,
        "particular_id": 2,
        "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "2014-10-21",
        "time": "12:12:12",
        "quote_id": 2,
        "repairman_id": 30,
        "particular_id": 2,
        "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    }

]
```

but when i try in the other side

```
class Call extends Eloquent 

public function particularCall() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Particular'); 
}
```

it return nothing ???

Comment: How are you calling the one that returns nothing?

Comment: Route::get('test', function() 
 {
  $Call = Call::find(2);
  return $Call->particularCall;
 });

Answer (score 1):

You should try with:

```
Route::get('test', function() { 
   $Call = Call::find(2); 
   return $Call->particularCall(); 
});
```

or

```
Route::get('test', function() { 
   $Call = Call::with('particularCall')->find(2); 
   return $Call->particularCall; 
});
```